# $B(t) = \frac{r'(t)\times r''(t)}{||r'(t) \times r''(t)||}$ proof

Tags: vector-analysis

$$N(t) = \frac{T'(t)}{|T'(t)|}$$

$$T(t) = \frac{r'(t)}{|r'(t)|}$$

$$r'(t) = T(t)\cdot|r'(t)|$$

$$r''(t) = T'(t)\cdot |r'(t)|+T(t)\cdot \frac{d}{dt}(|r'(t)|)$$

Now $$r'(t)\times r''(t) = |r'(t)|^{2}\cdot T(t)\times T'(t)$$

$$T(t)\times T'(t) = \frac{r'(t)\times r''(t)}{|r'(t)|^{2}}$$

Now $T(t)$ is already present. How to get $|T'(t)| \text{ to find } N(t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint :

Since $\vec{T}(t)$ is unit tangent vector, It follows that $\vec{T}(t).\vec{T}(t)=1$

differentiate with respect to $t$ you can get $\vec{T^{\prime}}(t).\vec{T}(t)=\vec{0}$

That is $\vec{T}(t)$ and $\vec{T^{\prime}}(t)$ are perpendicular

Comment: Thanx, can $$|T(t)\times T'(t)|$$ be written $|T'(t)|$ since $T(t)$ is a unit vector$$?

Comment: Since $B(t)=\frac{T(t)\times T'(t) }{|T(t)\times T'(t)|}$ you can use your $T(t)\times T'(t) = \frac{r'(t)\times r''(t)}{|r'(t)|^{2}}$

Comment: Aaahhaa....$T(t)\times T'(t) = \hat{n} |T(t)|\cdot |T'(t)| \cdot sin(pi/2)$ also T and T' perpendicular

Comment: That is correct!!

Comment: But you have already proved what you want